# Adding minizip breaks Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm attempting to add [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) to my project following the [WikiPage](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/wiki/PageName).  I've added it to my project and attempted to build, but now NSObjRuntime.h, NSObject.h and countless other header files are all having parsing issues!

I've included a screenshot of my workspace

[image: workspace]

and the errors...

[image: errors]

Some more details about the project.

- Building against iOS5.
- Using ARC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally got it figured out.  Instead of adding groups and then adding the files to those groups, I dragged and dropped the ZipArchive folder into the project.  In the dialog that pops up...I chose the "Create folder references for any added folders".

[image: Copy image]

This gave me BLUE folders within my workspace, and everything compiles fine now.

[image: Blue folders]

Though, now I need to figure out the difference between folder references and group references.

Comment: This allowed my project to compile. but now I cannot add #import "ZipArchive.h" it says file not found.

Comment: Nevermind. I know what the difference between Folder and Group is. I had to put #import "Encoding/ZipArchive/ZipArchive.h" as the folder I added was in the Encoding folder in my project. And that folder is relative to the place my file was added.

Answer (score 5):

The solution we found is to change the File Type for all .c file in folder minizip from **C-Source** to **Objective-C source** in the Identity and Type tab on the right-side.

It works for us.

Good luck

Answer (score 4):

The issue is probably caused by Objective-C in your C files. This could be caused by imports in your PCH. You need to wrap these in a `#ifdef __OBJC__`

i.e.

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#import "SomeObjecitveCFile.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Dragging and dropping the ZipArchive folder into the project did not work for me. Instead,
I dragged and dropped the minizip folder into the same folder where I added ZipArchive.h and ZipArchive.m files seperately. I chose the "Create folder references for any added folders".
Reason: In ZipArchive.h file we do

```
 #include "minizip/zip.h"
 #import "AppDelegate.h"
 #include "minizip/unzip.h"
```